# Is there a way to deform a model and then have the mesh stay that way, even without an armature?

Tags: modeling, mesh, armature, 3d-printing

I want to 3D print several pawns. I need them to be in different poses, but be the same general character. I can achieve this by re-meshing the posed object with another object, but I would like a less time consuming way.

How do I pose a mesh using an armature, then have the mesh stay that way, even without the armature which needs to be deleted for my print? preferably this would create a new mesh that I could print as my pawn(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can apply the armature modifier.

[image]

This will fix the mesh into it's pose, so you probably want to do this on a  duplicate of the model.

Comment: Yeah but now i can't delete the armature without the object freakin out.

Comment: Ok got it now tx!

Comment: I think if the mesh is freaking out then you can try Alt-P-> Clear Parent and Keep Transform.