# How do I delete an armature but keep the baked pose?

Tags: armature

According to my notes from when I have done this before:

**Q. How do I bake or fix the pose to the object?**
A. Pose the model and then switch to Object mode. Select the model (not the armature) or shift select all the parts of the object if it isn't one single mesh. Next, add a new modifier and choose "Armature". Make sure that the armature is moved to the top of the stack and in the Object dropdown menu, select the armature that you created and then press apply.

So the problem that I am having is that I have followed those directions exactly, but then when I delete my armature, my pose resets and I lose the pose. It doesn't seem that it baked it at all.

What is going on? How do I delete an armature but keep the baked pose?

Comment: Have you tried `Ctrl` `A` to apply rotation, scale and location in object mode, **before** deleting the armature?

Comment: Yes, and it I still get the same thing...as soon as I delete the armature it goes back to the original form.

Comment: I just did it with a very simple setup. A pipe elbow with an armature with two bones. I deformed it in pose mode, then in object mode I 1. Applied the armature modifier. 2. Applied rotation, scale and location. 3. Deleted the armature. And after this, the deformation remained.

Comment: Yeah I don't know what is going on. Thanks for confirming that I was doing it right. I will just have to save it out as an obj and re-import it for this model I guess.

Comment: I'm not really that experienced with Blender, and hardly at all with armatures, so if I were you, I'd wait awhile and someone else may come along with an answer. One thing though, if you upload your .blend to http://pasteall.org/blend and put the link in your question, it will be a lot easier to find the problem.

Comment: Apply the armature modifier

Comment: Never in my life have I had the odd kinds of problems that I am having lately. Things on my PC will randomly stop working. Today Blender would no longer snap a vertex to the 3D cursor position while constrained along an axis. I think I am having some deeper computer issues like a corrupt OS, unless gremlins are real. Please disregard this post. I was doing everything right it just wasn't working for  whatever reason.

Comment: This what your looking for?http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18495/is-there-a-way-to-deform-a-model-and-then-have-the-mesh-stay-that-way-even-with

Comment: And if it is solved, may you please give a detailed explanation in the form of an answer for future users?

Comment: I wish I could just delete this question. The problem really, is that my computer is having unexplainable random issues. I was doing everything correctly and it wasn't working and so that is why I asked the question, because I thought I was doing it wrong and there was some other way, which there is not.

Answer (score 4):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to apply all transformations
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to clear parent and keep transformation
3. Apply all modifiers

Answer (score 2):

Check where your cursor is on your scene.
Select your mesh: CTRL+A (Apply transformations).
Then,**Use ALT+P (keep transforms**) to separate it from your armature. 
Then select your mesh, CTRL+A (apply transformations) to zero out to current scene level.

Profit.

Comment: you are missing Apply Modifiers!